# Deleting many records from DB: Spring batch benefits?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, completable-future

**Scenario:**

Create a spring boot project that will, twice a month, do:

1. Read info from a master table, which contains which table to delete, and criteria for deletion
2. Find all the keys from the specified deletion table, which meet the deletion criteria
3. Actually delete all the records based on the keys found above.

Now, some tables can have large volumes of data, in order of millions of rows, but most will be smaller tables < 10k rows to delete.

**Question:**

Given the above scenario, my boss suggested we look into Spring Batch. I am trying to understand is there any particular benefit Spring Batch will provide? as opposed to a normal scheduler that spins of multiple threads, and each thread parallelly deleting records from tables specified in the Master table?

Comment: my advice is to test with native rdbms-query (pl-sql, or whatever). Should be faster. Also any schedule should be based on native rdbms-query (eg: means work exclusively with on rdbms provided environment: pl-sql, t-sql). Any usage through intermediary layer JPA/Hibernate can not be faster. (including any "intermediary schedulers" ... but this is another story)

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of spring batch in this scenario is that it breaks up a single transaction that can potentially involve millions of rows into multiple smaller transactions (assuming you use chunk processing).  If you try to delete millions of rows in a single transaction the rollback log for the transaction can be huge, which can make the database actually take much longer than it would for multiple small transactions.